# How can I model a Can-Be-A relationship in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, model, multiple-inheritance, composition

Let's say I have a `User` class, and a `User` can be an `Employee`, an `Applicant`, both (employed but applying for work elsewhere), or neither (unemployed and not applying for work).

How can I define this relationship in java such that a `User` can be cast to an `Employee` but only if they actually are employed, and likewise for the other scenarios (cannot be cast to an `Employee` or an `Applicant` if they are unemployed and not applying for work)?

Would this require a separate class that inherits from `User` for each combination i.e. `Employee`, `Applicant`, `EmployeeAndApplicant`?

Comment: Casting is validated at runtime. If you want to make sure it's the right type, check first.

Comment: You can use composition and/or multiple interfaces to support combinations.

Comment: It sounds like "being employed" and "applying" are states rather than inherent qualities of a `User`, so I would generally split those off into subrecords instead.

Comment: @shmosel yes, but if you use an interfaces, then a `User` can be cast to an `Employee` even if they aren't actually employed. So I suppose the question is how would this be modeled using composition?

Comment: I really don't understand your point about casting. Any time you use inheritance, there's the inherent "risk" of casting to an incorrect subtype. That's why there's a runtime error. In any case, casting in itself is usually a code smell.

Comment: @shmosel The problem is that if you make `User` implement an `Employee` interface, and then search among your users to see which `user is Employee` all users will pass that test, regardless of whether or not a user is actually employed _because_ you're making the base class implement `Employee`.

Comment: Why would `User` implement `Employee`?

Comment: @shmosel you're the one who mentioned using interfaces. if `User` implementing `Employee` is not what you meant then please provide an example of the solution you intended and remove ambiguity.

Comment: I meant that you can have some subclass of `User` that implements `Employee` or `Applicant` or both. But I tend to agree with @chrylis that inheritance may not be appropriate here.

Comment: @chrylis yes but all the methods that `Employee` require are irrelevant to `User` if they're not employed. you're saying put all the methods that `Employee` and `Applicant` require in `User` and call it a day, polymorphism not a good choice here?

Comment: @shoe I'm saying exactly the opposite. `User` should have references (foreign-key relationships in JPA) to `EmployeeRecord` and `ApplicantRecord`. Prefer composition to inheritance.

Comment: @chrylis so as per my original question, you're saying it is impossible without a third class (`EmployeeAndApplicant`) to be able to have a `User` that can polymorph to an `Employee` or `Applicant`, but only when they're actually employed or applying?

Comment: I'm saying it's a really bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Just to spell out what I think was meant in the comments (not tested)

```
public class User {

    /** this user’s employment, or null if unemployed */
    private EmployeeRecord employment;
    /** this user’s application, or null if not an applicant for any job */
    private ApplicantRecord application;

    // getters, setters etc.

}
```

You may even use, say, `Collection<ApplicantRecord>` to model that the user may be applying for more than one job at a time, if relevant.